# PGADMIN 4 Linux binary path

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to use backup and restore from PgAdmin4. I have set the binary path in preferences to /usr/bin where the pg_dump commands etc are. I am using a linux env which has pgadmin installed. After setting that path I am still getting an error that pg_dump is not found when it clearly is listed under that path. psql is started and running etc. What am I missing can anyone assist please?? Thanks!

```
'/usr/bin/pg_dump' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `/usr/bin/pg_dump` from the shell?

Comment: Turns out I was actually in the wrong EC2 instance Env that had pgadmin installed. Once I figured that part out and installed postgresql on the env the binary path worked as expected. Thanks for replying much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For proper execution of PgAdmin4, find the actual binary path in linux by the following command.

```
$ find / -name "pg_restore"
```

output

```
/usr/pgsql-14/bin/pg_restore
```

This will show the path of executable path of pg_dump, pg_dump_all, pg_restore etc. Just copy "/usr/pgsql-14/bin" and go to File -> preference ->path -> binary path -> PostgreSql Binay Path  and set the value according to your postgresql version.